# how to protect my cmd by username and password using btach file

Tags: cmd.exe, login

please be kind, i need help in creating batch file which will ask for username and password to access to cmd, like script protector, i have lot of users, they use my cmd lot and i want to put end for this, i really will pleasure and it will helpful if get any good answer or example fo this bat file

[like this script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhZLa.jpg)

Comment: when you say CMD, do you mean that users are using the command prompt, or are you saying that the users are using a batch file you wrote?

Comment: i was mean users are using command prompt, i want to stop this, by lock cmd, or use bat script

Comment: does this help? https://www.howtogeek.com/249007/how-to-disable-the-command-prompt-and-run-program-in-windows/

Comment: :) i tried before to disable it and i did, but i find it enabled from one of users, whatever, thanks frank for trying, if you have idea of how you can lock cmd tell me ;)

Comment: are these users admins on the box? are the PCs centrally managed by a domain? this isn't that hard if the systems and users are managed, but completely impossible if not.

Comment: are these users admins on the box? ==>yes,  are the PCs centrally managed by a domain?==> no,

Comment: What the **Windows version and edition** you're currently running on your PC?

Comment: What do you care what they do at the command prompt? "The use my CMD"?  This makes no sense.  Are they logging in as YOU?  Limit their rights and there is no difference or problem.  The whole premise of how you are managing this problem makes no sense to me.

Comment: What the **permission level** of those users?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @Jorge Luiz, i use win 10 pro x64 bit

Comment: @Señor CMasMas, they make another users using cmd

Comment: @Jorge Luiz, permission level is never notfiy me, i fix it by make it always notifiy me, thx ;)

Comment: So to solve this, you limit YOUR ACCOUNT to not be able to do this (maky yourself a regular user).  At the same time, you give yourself another account with admin privs that you will need to type in a password for when you need to do this stuff.  That is the intended way to solve this problem.